# ASP.NET How can i add superscript into a label control?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, formatting, label, superscript

For example currently, the value is set with `lblAmount.Text = Amount & " €"`

How can i add (dynamically) superscript to the **€** sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the SUP tag.

```
lblAmount.Text = Amount & "<sup>€</sup>"
```

Comment: Note: I just had an issue at a customer site using this approach whereby IE8 completely crashed out when it reached this page.  I was able to reproduce the same behaviour at the dev site, but only in IETester (not even my IE8 VMs, with IE on the same version as the customer site could reproduce the issue).  Removing the `<sup />` tags solved the issue.  I'm still baffled, having been unable to produce the same problem anywhere else...  BEWARE!

Answer (score 1):

You do this best by adding either a style attribute or by adding a class (and adding the style in a style tag or a css file.

```
<asp:Label id="lblAmount" runat="server"></asp:Label><asp:Label id="lblAmountSymbol" runat="server" CssClass="yourclass"></asp:Label>

span.yourclass {
    font-size:9px; 
    vertical-align:top; 
}
```

or

```
<asp:Label id="lblAmount" runat="server"></asp:Label><asp:Label id="lblAmountSymbol" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

and this, in your code file

```
Me. lblAmount.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontSize, "9px")
Me. lblAmount.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.VerticalAlign, "top")
```

You could also use the html equivalent sup:

```
Me. lblAmount.Text = Amount & " <sup>€</sup>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Goto Start->Programs->Accessories->System tools->Character Map
Now select this Character ² from the Characters listed.
Click Select
Click Copy

Then try to change the text of any control by pasting this Character in the Lable or Button Caption at Properties.

Even you can wrting code also like this:
Code\Button1.Text = "mm ²"\Code

This is working fine with me.
```