# superscript in asp label

Tags: asp.net

i wish to display a single label as "18th january 2011"... where 'th' hs to be in superscript.. how to do in asp.net with label??

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET How can i add superscript into a label control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989554/asp-net-how-can-i-add-superscript-into-a-label-control)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<asp:Label ID="name" runat="server">18<sup>th</sup>January 2011</asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The html tag for superscript is `<sup>`: you could concatenate the d, M, & Y elements with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>18<sup>th</sup> January 2011</label>
```