# Display footnote character in text

Tags: asp.net, text, formatting

I have a checkbox that the text needs to display a footnote character of '1' but can not figure out the  +  or & sequence to get it to display properly. Can anyone help?

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbSFAAViolationObserved3" runat="server" Text=" Ashtray(s) present^1" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET How can i add superscript into a label control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989554/asp-net-how-can-i-add-superscript-into-a-label-control)

Comment: Looks like it. Can someone click up on the answer below for me? I don't have enough rep yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the sup tag. like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbFootNote" runat="server" Text="footnote here<sup>1</sup>" />
```